# Google AppEngine Python: Class Not Defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine, class

In my Python-coded AppEngine application, I'm getting the following error code:

> NameError: global name 'PandaHugs' is not defined

I can't figure out why, as I define 'PandaHugs' above the place where it is called. Here's the code:

```
#!C:\Python25\python.exe -u

import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class PandasHugs(db.Model):
    message = db.StringProperty(required=False, multiline=False)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ListOfHugs = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PandasHugs")
        Adder = 0
        for PandasHugs in ListOfHugs:
            Adder = Adder + 1
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<h6>Panda has ' + str(Adder) + ' hugs!</h6>')
        self.response.out.write("<form action=\"/HugPanda\" method=\"post\"><div><input type=\"text\" name=\"PandaMessage\" value=\"A message for a panda.\"></div><div><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Hug a panda?\"></div></form></body></html>")


class HugAPanda(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        TheMessage = self.request.get('PandaMessage')
        HugForAPanda = PandaHugs(message=TheMessage)
        HugForAPanda.put()
        self.redirect('/main')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
  [('/', MainPage), ('/main', MainPage), ('/HugPanda', HugAPanda)],
  debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Please, name your variables in lowercase!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the class `PandasHugs` early in your code, but later you have:

```
HugForAPanda = PandaHugs(message=TheMessage)
```

Notice the singular form of Panda? What you want is

```
HugForAPanda = PandasHugs(message=TheMessage)
```

**Edit:** You also have `for PandasHugs in ListOfHugs:` in the `get()` method of your `MainPage` class. While there is technically nothing wrong with using the class name as a local variable of your method, it is confusing and hides the `PandasHugs` class in the `get()` method. Can I suggest something like `for hug in ListOfHugs`?